# How to get COMMAND + F to work with Selenium Javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am attempting to get my script to give me a true or false result based on COMMAND+F

I am sure that the following line is correct as it works for COMMAND + A. However, not for F.

```
await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Key.chord(Key.COMMAND, "f"))
```

Is this even possible, If so how? and in the event that I am able to get the search box to appear will I be able to add any string to the search box?

I am not getting any errors.

Comment: await driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body")).sendKeys(Key.COMMAND , "f") what happens if you use this

Comment: when opening a page without clicking anywhere on the page are you able to send this command ?

Comment: or you have to click somewhere on the page first and then send it ?

Comment: the browser's search function is outside of the DOM, so Selenium can't access.  Clipboard commands do work as the DOM has event handlers for those actions.

Comment: Is there a way to use another tool and Selenium to bypass the fact Selenium can not function outside the DOM?

Comment: robot in java... but not real sure you need "ctrl-f" in the first place.  XPATH is very good for searching the DOM.  Maybe explain your use-case.

Comment: I am trying to identify if the copy on the web page is true or false based on copy that I am pulling from a google sheet. If the copy is true (copy from my google sheet matches what is on the webpage) then that copy will be updated based on another column on sheets. If false then I want it to throw an error.

Comment: Hi pcalkins, thank you for the help. I have found a way around using cmd+f. Thank you for your input